# Updating id primary key in sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to make a query that involves the primary key of a table Users created as:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
        ID PRIMARY KEY,
        email           VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL,
        password        VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL,
        token           VARCHAR(32),
        firstname       VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL,
        lastname        VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL,
        gender          VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL,
        city            VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL,
        country         VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL
);
```

The problem is that the entries have no preceding ID entry within the table:

```
sqlite> select * from Users;
|test1@test1.com|pbkdf2:sha1:1000$1QH0MnIO$379005819d14d578684a54ccbed92716187b6
aed||test1|test1|male|test1|test1
|aaa@aaa.com|pbkdf2:sha1:1000$LhxdRneM$62e02ab5f50715a3f52ae018bc49178c6b31b31b|
97IEx8M9aHC8lmaU0IQtsgxd4lMLPYGm|aaa|aaa|male|aaa|aaa
|bbb@bbb.com|pbkdf2:sha1:1000$BqGePRKD$7252a3b9342f50375cd75be7c70280ea211662b5|
BPVo7nxOe1mx35jdMnaH6GY74JC1Tzh3|bbb|bbb|male|bbb|bbb
|ccc@ccc.com|pbkdf2:sha1:1000$IU7zEn6C$9511fe277e8ce1822b4de4823dac4402fad1b652|
fmfyrWSec8BmUAFhgiQF5mFhhN8jqXDw|ccc|ccc|male|ccc|ccc
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490100/no-autoincrement-for-integer-primary-key-in-sqlite3) question the table must be created using a primary integer key:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        email           VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL,
        password        VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL,
        token           VARCHAR(32),
        firstname       VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL,
        lastname        VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL,
        gender          VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL,
        city            VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL,
        country         VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL

);
```

Would it be possible to modify the primary key without recreating the table?

Comment: An `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` makes the column an alias for the rowid. Your rows still have a rowid even without it (`SELECT rowid FROM Users`). If you want an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` field, you'll have to recreate the table though.

Comment: I recreated the table.